# How to convert Mat to byte array, store the value and then convert it back again? java opencv

Tags: java, opencv, iris-recognition

I have a Mat image for my system and I want to be able to store it in my sqlite database. So I am thinking I need to try convert it to a byte array to be able to store it. But then Im not sure that is right because I'm unsure how to use the value I get if I was to access it from the db to be able to turn it back into its original Mat image.
Below is what I have come up with so far:

```
static byte[] matToByte(Mat mat) throws SQLException {
    int length = (int) (mat.total()*mat.elemSize());
    byte buffer[] = new byte[length];
    int converted = mat.get(0, 0, buffer);

    IrisInitialDatabase.addFeatures(converted);

    return buffer;

}

static Mat byteToMat(byte[] value) {
    Mat m = new Mat();
    m.put(0, 0, value);

    return m;
}
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save it to the database in Base64 format.

1. Mat to bitmap

   ```
   Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgba.cols(),
           rgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

   Utils.matToBitmap(rgba, image);

   Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) image;
   bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 600, 450, false);
   ```
2. bitmap to byte array

   ```
   ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
   byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
   ```

---save to database---

3. get mat back

   ```
   m = Highgui.imdecode(new MatOfByte(Base64.decode(base64ImageFromDB,0)),Highgui.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
   ```

Comment: thank you, I don't seem to have the Bitmap type, do you know how i can get it, I don't think it was included in my opencv lib

Comment: Bitmap is default android library
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

just import

       `import android.graphics.Bitmap;`

Comment: I'm glad it works, please mark my answer as correct. :)

Comment: im getting a stub error, it says is caused by the first line, do you think this would be something to do with the format/colour my mat img was originally in?

Comment: How do you get your Mat image?  Try debug it and check if it's the right format. Matrix should have columns, rows, etc.

Comment: Although this answer works, it's probably not optimal. Base64 adds about 30% overhead to the size. For small tables, that might work, but for bigger tables, it'd be best to store it as a byte array